# Mysql Multiple Foreign Key for a attribute in table

Tags: mysql

I want to design a database for e-learning. Here is the case.
"Each subject has 2 hierarchy i.e. ScoringComponent and Competency.Each hierarchy is updated every period. Each hierarchy has unlimited depth-level. The lowest level of the ScoringComponent should be mapped to one or more lowest level of competency hierarchy."[Relation between the ScoringComponent and Competency Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfOqm.jpg)

Based on the case, i tried to design the database. The result is like [Database Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygHLA.png).

The issue in the database design is the multiple Foreign Key for Year-Period Attributes.

From this issue, i want to create the table without Foreign Key and handle the data validity in the application code.

Is it okay for me to remove the Foreign key from the table? and is there any suggestion for my case? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would not move away from using a foreign key in your table, if you need it.

Are you the only one that will know how the data is arranged in the database?

Comment: No. all developers in my team should know the data flow in the database. I want to use the foreign key. but i have no idea how the database design should be if i use the foreign key.